# Invertibility of $I + AB(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I am dealing with a matrix $$I + AB(x)$$ where $A, B(x)$ are square $n\times n$ real matrices and $x$ is a real variable.  I want to find the values of $x$ for which this matrix is singular (and then an eigenvector).  $A$ is invertible and $B(x)$ is invertible for the values of $x$ I am looking for. I looked into:

- Determinant: plainly awful
- Gaussian elimination: a bit better but leads to $n$ lengthy equations
- Neumann series: useless because it is not a necessary and sufficient condition
- Generalized eigenvalue: not very familiar with this theory but looks more suitable for numerical approximation

Any other ideas would be very appreciated!  (For clarity I am hoping to find a somewhat palatable equation for x...)
Thanks
p

Comment: Invertibility of $I+AB(x)$ is equivalent to that of $A^{-1}+B(x)$ if $A$ is invertible. It might be of use..

Comment: Is the dependence of B on x linear, and does the variable x appear in each element of B? If so, then the determinant of @Berci's matrix will be an nth order polynomial. To find where it is singular you just need to find the zeros of that determinant, and you could use Newton's method or similar numerical scheme to find them.

Comment: B(x) is not linear but it is a "nice" analytic function

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $B(x)$ is a nice analytic function of $x$, maybe polynomial.
Determinant is not necessarily so awful: its computation (for a particular matrix) takes about the same time as Gaussian elimination.  You might 
try Newton's method, using [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) to compute the derivatives.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! B(x) is not polynomial but it is indeed analytic and expandable in power series. I had a brief look into Jacobi's formula earlier and I was a bit concerned about the adjugate matrix, but perhaps it's doable.  Presumably I can't use the simplified formula without adjugate involving the inverse of $I+AB(x)$...

Comment: If the adjugate is a problem you could use a [quasi-Newton method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method) that approximates the derivative rather than actually computing it.

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the equation a bit more using the [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A$ as follows:$$A=UDV\implies |I+AB(x)|{=|I+UDVB(x)|\\=|U^H+DVB(x)|\\=|U^HU+DVB(x)U|\\=|I+DVB(x)U|\\\triangleq |I+DC(x)|}$$where $D$ is diagonal, $U$ and $V$ are unitary and $C(x)\triangleq VB(x)U$, but this time, **the singularity of $I+AB(x)$ is equivalent to the singularity of $I+DC(x)$, with $D$ being diagonal.** Any constraint on $C(x)$ then, can be converted to that for $B(x)$, and as **@RobertIsrael** said, if $B(x)$ is a nice function, then so is $C(x)$. I think this might reduce the computation time as $D$ is diagonal. Even you can use $|D^{-1}+C(x)|$ to decide.

Comment: Thank you.  Why SVD rather than eigendecomposition? To avoid complexes?

Comment: Your welcome. Also eigendecomposition looks much helpful but is not as general as SVD which applies to **all** kind of matrices [ even non-square :) ]. The *eigendecomposition* is useful only for ***diagonalizable*** matrices.